# How can you put the android emulator into sleep mode?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there a way to get the android emulator into sleep mode?

Comment: Programmatically or otherwise?

Comment: otherwise...sorry I did not specify

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>. That should at least send you back to the lock screen.

Comment: does this emulate sleep mode though or just lock the phone?

Comment: @ninjasense: Pressing F7 simulates pressing the power button.  Of course, you can also click on your emulators power button.

Comment: I think this is not the correct answer to the question... I am also trying to find out how to put the emulator to sleep just as a phone does - but the lock screen is NOT sleep mode. :-(

Comment: @Zordid you're right, the question was how to emulate the display timeout e.g. after 15 secs of inactivity. So you can check whether your app disables standby mode correctly.

Answer (score 5):

You might try `PowerManager.gotosleep()`

Answer (score 5):

Press F7+F2 to get your emulator locked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` -> `Display` -> `Screen timeout`

Selecting one of the options in `Screen timeout` will allow you to change the time it takes the emulator to go to sleep.