# How to simulate sleep mode on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Some users of my Android application report bugs when the mobile enters sleep/power saving mode.

I would like to test that issue on the Android Virtual Device. Is it possible to simulate the mobile entering in sleep/power saving mode on the AVD ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've took a look at that other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411369/how-can-you-put-the-android-emulator-into-sleep-mode) but the answers seems to deal with locking the phone - I would like to switch it in sleep mode.

Comment: press <kbd>F7</kbd>

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411369/how-can-you-put-the-android-emulator-into-sleep-mode/4411432#4411432

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try the following on emulator

1. Go to `Settings`
2. Go to `Developer options`
3. Un-check `Stay awake` (3rd option from the top)

The emulator will go to sleep after 1 min (default setting) if not changed.

Press the power button [image] to wake up the emulator.

`Developer options` is not enabled by default, to enable it, do the following:

1. Go to `Settings`
2. Click `About emulated device`
3. Click `Build number` 7 times, you should be notified that `Developer options` is now enabled
4. Go back and you should see `Developer options`

Comment: If this option does not appear, you have to enable developer mode by

1. go to settings -> System -> About emulated device

2. click 7 times on the build number

Then you find it in the developer options

Comment: @KurtHuwig, do you mean using the Adnroid 'Settings Applet' or using the ... on the developer sidebar next to the emulated phone on my PC?   I can't find how to turn on Developer Options in the emulator.

Comment: @PeteAlvin - the Android Settings applet inside the emulated phone. The instructions for turning it on are given in the second half of the answer. (This is the same as on any real Android phone.)

Comment: On newer phones, once Developer Options are turned on, they are found as Settings / System / Advanced / Developer Options. HOWEVER, see other answers: you don't need to do anything shown in this answer; just click the emulated power button to turn screen off (just like on a real phone)!

Comment: Is this only for screen sleep or actual deep sleep (doze mode)? I find that screen sleep alone will not trigger most of sleep-related bugs because it's the deep sleep that can hibernate or even close your app and also stop background processes of your app, if not implemented correctly.

Answer (score 39):

On emulator, go Settings/Security/Screen lock change from 'None' to 'Swipe' 
[image]

Then, click 'power' button on right control bar to turn off screen, and press again to turn on screen. Now the lock screen will show up. 
[image]

Comment: What the hell, this just sleeps the screen. My emulator is still consuming bananzas of cpu. All four. And you hardly need the swipe option for that. Just click the power button.

Answer (score 26):

The `Power Button` on the sidebar next to emulator will do it.

The hotkey on my Mac is `⌘ P`

*Note: You will need to set Lock Screen using Swipe instead of None*

Comment: You can use `⌘ P` to unlock it again.

Comment: Still consumes lots of CPU.  Same amount it seems. Just goes black.

Answer (score 7):

To put the device to sleep using command line, run:
`adb shell input keyevent 223`

To wake the device from sleep using command line, run:
`adb shell input keyevent 224`

For more info about key events you can send with ADB, check out the `KEYCODE_...` constants for [KeyEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent), e.g.:

```
/** Key code constant: Sleep key.
 * Puts the device to sleep.  Behaves somewhat like {@link #KEYCODE_POWER} but it
 * has no effect if the device is already asleep. */
public static final int KEYCODE_SLEEP           = 223;

/** Key code constant: Wakeup key.
 * Wakes up the device.  Behaves somewhat like {@link #KEYCODE_POWER} but it
 * has no effect if the device is already awake. */
public static final int KEYCODE_WAKEUP          = 224;
```

Answer (score 3):

Somehow fn + F7 doesn't work on my mac. So what I use instead is:

`adb shell input keyevent 26`

This sends the POWER KEY event and will turn off the screen. Note: It will not show that the screen is off. Image wills tay. But you can't interact with it. As soon as you do `adb shell input keyevent 26` again, you will see the lock screen indicating, that the device was off before.

Answer (score 1):

By pressing  <kbd>F7</kbd>  you can emulate sleep mode in your emulator.