# Cannot wake up Android emulator from sleep mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I need to test the behavior of my app in sleep mode. How to enable sleep mode, I found in this [Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476373/how-to-simulate-sleep-mode-on-android-emulator). As stated, about 1min after the screen of emulator goes to black.

The problem is now, I cannot wake the emulator back up again. No clicking and not hotkeys (F7, CTRL+H, etc.) What do I do wrong. Or do I habe a misunderstanding with the sleep mode, in general.

In principle, I could use a real device, but here I have not control when the phones goes to (deep) sleep, what makes it difficult to test.

Comment: Do you use Mac?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add: Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I have the same problem. I cannot wake the emulator by pressing the power button. I turned off "stay awake" in the dev options (I need it to test my app). I'm using Mac and emulator 26.0.0 on nexus 5X API 25 x86.

Comment: The problem is not always reproducible though, it seems to happen rarely (not sure under what conditions).

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior on Android Emulator 4.2.2 (SDK 17) running on Windows 10. Once it gets to sleep mode, it never returns back no matter if my application under test is running or not.

Answer (score 3):

I found that calling the emulator actually wakes up the phone as well.

[image: android emulator call function]

Comment: As stupid as this is, it's the only thing I've found that works. Thanks. +1

Comment: Not working in Marshmallow (need try a lot of thing and reboot to works), but Nougat works.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by checking "Stay awake" in "Settings -> Developer options -> Stay awake (screen will never sleep while charting)". And make sure set in emulator settings UI "(three dots) -> Battery -> Charger connection -> AC Charger"

Comment: The problem is the initial question was related to observe the behavior when the phone enters sleep mode. Your solution practically does not allow the phone to enter the sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

I also saw this problem with old Android version emulators (4.2, 4.3). If u actually wait for 20-30 seconds , emulator does wake up :) I dont know why so long...

Answer (score 0):

I found that closing the Emulator and then restarting in the Android Device Manager got it back on for me.