# Can't simulate sleep mode on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-service, android-wake-lock

I am trying to put my emulators into sleep mode to test some behavior.
For this, I deactivate the charger, set the battery to "uncharging" and a low battery %. Then I lock the screen over the power button (swipe to unlock is activated).

Then I start some background operation (for example an IntentService) without holding a wake lock and leave the app, but everything just keeps running as if the screen was on.
The emulator seems to not fall into sleep.

Not a duplicate since I am already following these exact steps (as described above)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate sleep mode on Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476373/how-to-simulate-sleep-mode-on-android-emulator)

Comment: Not a duplicate, since I already follow these steps (as you can see from my description)